# Не работает if(TypeImg.src == "dor.gif") тем самым не выводит alert()

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите, тоже самое с value у input работало, а здесь нет, если что, вот ссылка на страничку:
duoxx.github.io

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Tutorial</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="main.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function ClickButton (TypeImg) {
       if(TypeImg.src == "dor.gif"){
           alert ("hello");
       } 
        
    }
         
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
<img alt="Doritos" src="dor.gif" onclick="ClickButton (this)" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В `TypeImg.src` попадает полный путь к изображению, потому равенство не выполняется. Так что либо проверяйте на полное совпадение с абсолютным путем, либо на неполное совпадение регуляркой, либо введите даполнительный атрибут и по нему проверяйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения именно того, что указано в `src` вашего изображения можно воспользоваться `getAttribute('src')`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="main.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ClickButton(TypeImg) {
      if (TypeImg.getAttribute('src') == "dor.gif") {
        alert("hello");
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img alt="Doritos" src="dor.gif" onclick="ClickButton (this)" style="cursor:pointer;" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Я начал изучать javascript недавно скорее по этому :)